# Dynamic duration for SCSS animation based on current attributes

Tags: css, animation, sass, css-animations

I came across the [following progress bar](https://codepen.io/simeydotme/pen/IrGqz). However, I noticed that the pulse animation on the bar components has a constant duration which means it will play much faster the longer the colored bar gets. The corresponding (shortened) code is the following:

```
.progress {
    &__bar {
        animation: pulse 2s ease-out infinite;
    }
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        background-position: -50% center, right center, left center;
    }

    100% {
        background-position: 150% center, right center, left center;
    }
}
```

Using a short `$bar.css({ width: percent + "%" });` the bar gets stretched and thus the pulse animation gets faster as well. Is there any way to rewrite the animation s.t. it will always have the same speed, no matter how long the progress bar is?

Comment: JavaScript .animate() method is a viable solution? If so, I can elaborate a proper answer

Comment: @ArthurCantarela It really depends on the implementation. If it is something that I only call when activating the progress bar for example and don't have to continuously take care of it is viable, yeah.

Comment: check out if my solution is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've [forked your progress bar](https://codepen.io/arthurcantarela/pen/QxjjOx) and made some scss changes only. I've played with wrappers, absolute positioning and hiding overflow.

I've create a div `class="progress__bar--bkg"` and also a `@mixin innerBkg` to deal with background only with a fixed width, and a div `class="progress__bar--wrap"` to hide only background overflow (I've tried without it at first but `overflow: hidden;` affected also text and bar end's glow. About the last, I've changed `z-index: 1` for `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

Comment: The animation still feels a bit off and I figured out what it is actually in both versions. I'd like the animation to go over the colored part (and not over the entire bar) beyond the current percentage, pause for a second and repeat without letting the animation go to "100%" all the time. The initial example has this behaviour but is speeding up since the 2s duration is hardcoded. Your proposed solution has a smooth (and adjustable) speed but it has much longer "downtimes" since your animation moves beyond the end of the bar.

Comment: Got it, I'll improve my answer soon